# what is the meaning of 'to wear one's breeches out' and 'rat-gutted'?

Tags: expressions, adjectives, compounds, literature

I am quoting from the *Memoirs of Sherlock Holmes, The Gloria Scott* by Arthur Conan Doyle:

> Now, you don't think it likely that a man who could do anything is going to wear his breeches out sitting in the stinking hold of a rat-gutted, beetle-ridden, mouldy old coffin of a China coaster?

I found an definition of *'wear the breeches'* in the free dictionary but it doesn't fit the context.

As for *'rat-gutted'* I couldn't find anything.

Comment: You have to look up *wear out* to understand what a lot of sitting will do to the seat of your pants.

Comment: The descriptor _rat-gutted_ is probably not closely connected with 'rat gut' in the modern slang usage. I'd say it's a more visceral variant of _rat infested_. // A man of action is not going to take things lying down (or sitting down).

Comment: A "China coaster" is a cargo ship, and the hold of such a ship is (or was) sometimes referred to as its "bowels" or "guts."  To be "rat-gutted" would then simply be to have rats in its guts—that is, in its hold.